# boost::asio::steady_timer() vs sleep() which one should I use?

Tags: c++, boost

The following two program are same from run time point of view, both waiting for 5 seconds to continue. One uses boost::asio::steady_timer, another uses sleep(), which one is better?

1) Use sleep()

```
$ cat b.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
    sleep(5);
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}

$ g++ b.cpp && ./a.out
start
end
```

2) Use boost::asio::steady_timer

```
$ cat c.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(5));
    t.wait();
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

$ g++ c.cpp -lpthread -lboost_system && ./a.out
start
end
```

Comment: have you considered `std::this_thread::sleep_for` from the standard `<thread>` library?

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko, I don't know 'std::this_thread::sleep_for' before see your comments, it seems a very good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

```
sleep(5)
```

- meh: relies on the `unistd.h` header, which is nonstandard and posix-specific, which may or may not be a problem, but is something to consider
- con: only takes integer so you don't have the option to sleep for sub-seconds, and can be unclear that it means 5 *seconds* and not some other unit.

2)

```
boost::asio::io_context io;
boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(5));
t.wait();
```

- meh: relies on boost, not a problem if you're already including another boost library, but would be overkill just for this purpose
- con: depends on an `io_context`
- pro: uses `boost::asio::chrono` for defining the time to sleep which can give you more granularity and more clarity

3)

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
```

- pro: standard library function (C++11 and up)
- pro: uses `std::chrono` for defining the time to sleep which can give you more granularity and more clarity

*note: if you are pre C++11, boost also has* `this_thread::sleep_for`

Comment: Note `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` will not be interrupted by signal from system. `sleep()` will.

Comment: U can use `5s` instead of `std::chrono::seconds(5)` with C++14 `std::chrono_literals`