# What is the difference between using a boost steady_timer and a sleep in a thread?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have difficulties figuring out how is boost::steady_timer with callback better than a simple sleep() in a thread. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111705/boostasiosteady-timer-vs-sleep-which-one-should-i-use) I concluded that the **only** obvious benefit is time granularity.

My question is a bit different than the one in the link, so I would be grateful for explanation.

Here is the source code for 2 applications:

**c.cpp**

```
unsigned i = 0;
void f(error_code e, ba::steady_timer& t){
    cout << "Waiting: "<< i++ << endl;
    sleep(2);
    t.async_wait(boost::bind(f,_1, std::ref(t)));
}

int main()
{
    ba::io_service ios;
    ba::steady_timer t(ios, seconds(5));
    t.async_wait(boost::bind(f,_1, std::ref(t)));

    ios.run();

    return 0;
}
```

**d.cpp**

```
unsigned i = 0;
void f() {
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Waiting: "<< i++ << endl;
        sleep(2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread th(f);
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, I expected that a **sleep()** version would show more CPU consumption (just because I read this in a book:

*"The bad solution creates a thread that does the checking and then sleeps for 5 seconds. This is a lame solution that eats a lot of system resources and scales badly."*
)

But, running both apps and checking them with `ps` on Linux Mint showed no difference at all.

So why should one prefer steady_timer or any other timer?

```
dim@laptop:~/Documents/test$ ps -C c -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
dim      11328  9486  0 18:21 pts/1    00:00:00 ./c
dim@laptop:~/Documents/test$ ps -C d -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
dim      11329  9486  0 18:21 pts/1    00:00:00 ./d
dim@laptop:~/Documents/test$
```

Comment: If all you want is to sleep with ms precision, then there's [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for). But sleeping is rarely what you really want in the first place. What you usually want is to wait for some event from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is waiting for the 2 seconds, than you can just call sleep from the main thread. But that's not what usually needs to be done by the multi threaded program.
Now Imagine that you have more than one callback, running 2 threads just to sleep for the 1 and 2 seconds each would be rather wasteful. With the timer on the other hand you can do a lot of thing in the same thread, or even in a pool of threads.